# Migrating a relational DB into AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a terabyte size SQL Server DB table which has only two columns:

1. Id,
2. HTML Content

There are few applications that call this Table to retrieve the HTML content by providing the Id of the row.

The DB is residing On-premises, and the maintenance cost and size of it is getting higher and higher. I am thinking to move this DB into **AWS Dynamo DB**. Reason I have choose Dynamo DB is the cost and the performance I have read about it.

- Are the any concerns I should know about before choosing Dynamo DB?
- Are the any other services in AWS that I could possibly use over
  Dynamo DB?

I understand that SQL Server is a Relational DB, while DynamoDB is no sql. And it seems a No Sql DB could be a potential solution for this scenario. I have no kind of joins nor transactions against that Table. All I am doing with the table is to Insert, and Select.

Comment: Dynamo DB is NoSql DB, SQL Server is relational DB - it's like comparing apples to oranges. You should check [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) ?

Comment: @alfasin, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the any concerns I should know about before choosing Dynamo DB?

As with any NoSql bigdata DB, Dynamo is "eventually consistent", so, if your application writes and then immediately reads the same record - you should expect failures (inconsistencies).

I'm not familiar with "Prem" and assuming you mean that you're working with your private servers I feel obligated to provide the following warning: working in the cloud is very different from working with your own servers: requests fail more often, latency pattern is different and you should architect your software to handle these sort of issues. If you're planning on moving to the cloud I'd start with migrating your application and leave the DB to be last.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need real time updates of your data, You should reconsider moving on Dynamo. Also dynamo is useful when you do need a dynamic number of columns for each row. So except the cost, i don't see any benefits here. 
If you don't need realtime updates, you can look into AWS Redshift or Google BigQuery, and these will be cheaper solutions compare to Dynamo.

Like you have mentioned, you just have two columns, take a look into "redis" also. A plain key value structure will help in performance. But since Redis stores everything in the Physical memory, costing will be high and you'll still need permanent storage/ DB like SQL, MySQL. So in terms of performance, yes you ll be able to see huge difference. but you'll be more thn the current cost.

How about AWS Aurora? At least AWS claims of 1/10th of cost compare to other SQL/MySQL instances. It have backward compatibility also.